# Openlayers rotation broken when using precompose to clip a layer

Tags: openlayers-3

After updating Openlayers to >4.0 map rotation is completely broken when using a `precompose` hook:

```
function precompose(event) {
    var context = event.context;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(100, 0);
    context.lineTo(100, 100);
    context.lineTo(0, 100);
    context.lineTo(0, 0);
    context.closePath();

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 5, 25, 0.75)";
    context.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to save the canvas context, for more information see [MDN CanvasRenderingContext2d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save)

```
function precompose(event) {
    var context = event.context;
    context.save(); // be sure to save the context before anything is done
    // ...
}
```

Also, use `context.restore()` in the `postcompose` hook.